# Comparing one day worth of data from S3 buckets faster

Tags: python, validation, amazon-s3, hive, qubole

Consider 2 data flows below

```
1. Front End Box ----> S3 Bucket-1

2. Front End Box ----> Kafka --> Storm ---> S3 Bucket-2
```

The logs from the boxes are being transferred to S3 buckets. The requirement is to replace flow 1 by flow 2.

Now the data needs to validated between `Bucket-1` and `Bucket-2` to guarantee that flow 2 can be used.

Following technological options were tried :

```
1. Python : boto3 Apis
2. Qubole
```

Both work on a limited data set, qubole is more scalable than python script. But still it takes very long time to do it(never finished, had to kill after running overnight). We are looking at half billion entries here.

**Query**

```
SELECT
    count(*)
FROM
    TableA LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
        ON TableA.id = TableB.id
WHERE
    TableB.id IS NULL
    AND TableA.id IS NOT NULL
```

**Question**

Any suggestion for tools, ways to achieve this faster ?

Are there any ways to avoid the join ?

Comment: Where do you host your `Front End Box` ? If you are on AWS then you can look into AWS Lamda.

Comment: Yes it is AWS. Will take a look at Lamda

Comment: You can try to log things using AWS CloudWatch and then run your validation in AWS Lambda and create temp files which you can move to S3 with `python`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally was able to avoid the join. Following solution works fine

```
select sum_cat, count(*)
FROM
(
   select id, sum(category) as sum_cat 
   from 
   (
       select distinct id, 1 as category
       from Table-1

       UNION ALL 

       select distinct id, 1 as category
       from Table-2 

       UNION ALL 

       select distinct id, 2 as category
       from Table-3

       UNION ALL 

       select distinct id, 2 as category
       from Table-4

  )all_ids
   group by log_id
)a
 group by sum_cat;
```

**Explanation**

1. The data comparison it to be done with the data from `Table-1` and `Table-2` with that in `Table-3` and `Table-4`
2. So we assign a `category` to id from these set of tables
3. All the ids from set A will have `category = 1` and set B records have `category = 2`
4. Now we sum of the category values and group by ids. So when id is present in both sets it will have value 3. The ids present only in set A will have value 1, which are missing records.